# how to bring a part towards an edge loop

Tags: transforms, edges

The two separate pieces in the picture were actually a single piece. Then I removed a section and there you see the gap between two sections. So they are already aligned and have same number of edges.

I want to bring the whole section on the right towards left and join to the piece on the left by joining their edges. Again, **not** **just** move the edge. Bring the whole piece on the right to join to the piece on the left and join by edges. How?  [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For blender 4.0 + :**

First, select the right part, press G, then B to set a snap point

[image]

choose any vertex on the side loop, and move it towards the oposite vertex. It should snap the piece in the correct position

[image]

Then select the whole model and merge by distance

[image]

**For previous versions of blender:**

Enable Snapping (or press CTRL while editing), set the "Snap To" mode to vertex and the "Snap With" to active (in this case the closest mode would have worked too), then select a vertex on the side loop of the object on the right and move it towards the left piece. Select everything and merge by distance

[image]

Comment: thanks it works. But after snapping the right piece to left piece, why do I still need to merge by distance? I already have what I want

Comment: also it seems B is shortcut for something called box select. but now it worked as snap. and I looked shortcut for snap and it is something else. confused a little here. what is B for. i mean obviously it allowed me to snap here but it is not listed as shortcut for snap. confused

Comment: @upstream Alex used `B` as an option with active _Move_ tool (`G`). `B` is _Box Select_ while not using another tool. And the _Merge by Distance_ because right now the vertices of the left and right piece are just laying together in the same location, they are not connected (unless you had the _Auto Merge_ option enabled). If the pure visual connection is enough for you okay, for any further operations which depend on a single connected edge, you will get more issues.

Comment: thanks. if we wanted to do this grab and then snap by menu how would we do it? also, i lost track of where i joined them. how can i find those double edge loops on each other where I joined them, and make them one?

Comment: You cannot select options from the menu while you are actively operating a tool. It's like holding `Shift` to move something slower - it cannot be chosen beforehand in a menu. It's a contextual tool option. For the edge loops: just select all with `A` and then `M` to merge. Assuming you do not have a mesh full of areas with duplicate geometry it will only merge you've put together (and even if there were lots of other duplicate vertices it's probably better to have them all merged).

Answer (score 0):

You could also select the two edge loops, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> then choose *Bridge Edge Loops*, and then scale X (or which axis you are on) to `0`.

Make sure you have *Auto-Merge* on, so it only becomes one edge loop.

Comment: The OP wants to move the whole object to the other one.

Comment: how can i turn auto merge on. where. and you are aware that I do not just want to bridge the gap, but move the whole piece as I stated in my question?