# How to quickly select object vertex and snap that object to another object vertex

Tags: snapping, origin, 3d-cursor

When using AutoDesk Inventor, there is a option called "Grip Snap" where you select a point. Go to another object and select a point. You then move the original object to where you selected.

In Blender you can select a Vertex, Shift + S -> Cursor to Selected. Set the origin to the 3D cursor.

[image: First image]

Then select the Vertex to where you want to move the object to and set the 3D cursor to the Vertex. You can then move your object to the 3D cursor. This works well but a little cumbersome.

[image: second image]

Is there a way to speed up this process?

**I have tried using Snap with Vertex** and find it sometimes difficult to use. If I have multiple objects stacked on top of each other, it's easy to snap to the wrong object.

I have started working on a script that could do this.

```
# Blender Python script to move the 3D cursor to a selected vertex in edit mode
# and set the origin of the selected object to the 3D cursor.

import bpy
import bmesh

# Ensure we are in edit mode
if bpy.context.object.mode != 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# Ensure we have a vertex selected
selected_verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
if not selected_verts:
    raise ValueError("No vertex selected.")

# Get the location of the first selected vertex
selected_vertex_location = obj.matrix_world @ selected_verts[0].co

# Move the 3D cursor to the selected vertex
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = selected_vertex_location

# Switch to object mode to set the origin
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Set the origin to the 3D cursor
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')

# Print a success message
print("The 3D cursor has been moved to the selected vertex and the origin of the object has been set to the 3D cursor.")
```

Comment: Since blender 4.0 there is a new way to snap objects (set snap base). Works in both edit and object mode
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/311590/158207

Answer (score 3):

**Object-Mode Snapping**

Several methods. All illustrated here, with the magnet switched **off**, set to snap 'To: Vertex', and activated with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, only when needed.

**Snap with 'Closest'**

('Closest' at the start of a move.) This encourages a workflow where the source is transformed roughly into place, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - snapped with a second move:

[image]

**Snap with 'Center'**

Here. 'Center' refers to the current Pivot Point. If you set the Pivot to 3D Cursor, then you can <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> - drag the 3D Cursor. Then holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> allows you to snap the cursor while moving it. That becomes your snap-source, for a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> governed move.

[image]

**Using 'B' after starting a transform**

Since version 4ish, you have been able to set the snap source during a transform , by using the <kbd>B</kbd> key. That sets the transform to nothing, while you select the source.. here illustrated with a <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> scale, followed by <kbd>B</kbd>, and then holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for the snap:

[image]

Also worth knowing, either while setting the snap-source with <kbd>B</kbd>, or the snap-target while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> transforming, you can use the <kbd>A</kbd> key when a point is  highlighted. That will set the source or target to the **average** of the points over which you have pressed  <kbd>A</kbd> .

Answer (score 0):

I wanted more control on where my objects were snapping to similar to Inventor. I also wanted to be able to move around my scene when selecting the 2 objects. I do not think you can do that with CTRL.

I have a script that will select a Vertex, move the 3D cursor to the Vertex and make the Vertex the object origin.

```
# Blender Python script to move the 3D cursor to a selected vertex in edit mode
# and set the origin of the selected object to the 3D cursor.

import bpy
import bmesh

# Ensure we are in edit mode
if bpy.context.object.mode != 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# Ensure we have a vertex selected
selected_verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
if not selected_verts:
    raise ValueError("No vertex selected.")

# Get the location of the first selected vertex
selected_vertex_location = obj.matrix_world @ selected_verts[0].co

# Move the 3D cursor to the selected vertex
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = selected_vertex_location

# Switch to object mode to set the origin
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Set the origin to the 3D cursor
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')

# Print a success message
print("The 3D cursor has been moved to the selected vertex and the origin of the object has been set to the 3D cursor.")
```

Then I select the Vertex on the second object and move the 3D cursor there.

I select the original object and move the object to the 3D cursor.